# what is 'node:6856' warnig?

Tags: json, node.js

**This error came up when I tried running server. what should I do?**

> (node:6856) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   Server running on port ${port} { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect
>   to server [ds263172.mlab.com:63172] on first connect
>   [MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.171.245.223:63172] at
>   Pool. (D:\Learning &
>   Interest\Computer\Web\projects\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)
>   at emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7) at
>   Connection. (D:\Learning &
>   Interest\Computer\Web\projects\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:317:12)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30) at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7) at Socket.
>   (D:\Learning &
>   Interest\Computer\Web\projects\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:246:50)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30) at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) at emitErrorNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8) at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11) at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9) name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

---

Comment: Are the first 2 sentences not perfectly telling you what the warning means and what you should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `MongoClient.connect(...)` statement add `{useNewParser: true}`. Your connect statement should look something like this:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning suggests you need to use the updated URL parser

USE this for [Reference](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/442)

Comment: how can i do that ?